# ODE of Boost Converter

Tags: control

I was wondering if anyone can confirm if this is right or not or if I am even on the right track

The ON State: 
[image]

- Node VL: \$ -\int\frac{V_{IN}}{L}=0\$
- Node VC: \$C\dot V_C+\frac{V_C}{R}=0\$

[image]

- Node VC:\$\frac{V_C-V_{IN}}{L}+C\ddot V_C+\frac{\dot V_C}{R}=0\$
- SSA MODEL:
  \$\frac{V_C}{L}-\frac{V_C*d}{L}\frac{-V_{IN}}{L}+C\dot V_C*d+C\ddot V_C-C\ddot V_C*d+\frac{\dot V_C}{R}-\frac{\dot V_C*d}{R}+\frac{V_C*d}{R}=0\$

where (variables)

- \$V_c = Capacitor\ Voltage \$
- \$ D = Duty \ Cycle\$

Assuming its right, I need to linearize it due to \$V_C*d\$ isn't linear.

*\$V_{CE}\$ as in Voltage of capacitor at equilibrium , not VCE of BJT.

Finding Equilibrium points, I want to linearize it around \$V_{CE} = 5V\$ so finding De and assuming all initial conditions are = 0

Where
\$C = 0.000272F\$
\$L = 0.000047242H\$
\$R = 2\Omega\$

\$\frac{5}{0.000047242}-\frac{5*d_e}{0.000047242}-\frac{3.3}{0.000047242}+\frac{5*d_e}{2}=0\$

Solving \$D_e = 0.34\$

Equilibrium Points
\$V_{CE} = 5V\$
\$D_E = 0.34\$

Linearization:

\$(\frac{\partial \frac{V_C}{L}}{\partial V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial \frac{V_C}{L}}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})-
(\frac{\partial \frac{V_C*d}{L}}{\partial V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial \frac{V_C*d}{L}}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})-
(\frac{\partial \frac{V_{IN}}{L}}{\partial V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial \frac{V_{IN}}{L}}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})+
(\frac{\partial C\dot V_C*d}{\partial \dot V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial C\dot V_C*d}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})+
(\frac{\partial C\ddot V_C}{\partial \ddot V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial C\ddot V_C}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})-
(\frac{\partial C\ddot V_C*d}{\partial \ddot V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial C\ddot V_C*d}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})+
(\frac{\partial \frac{\dot V_C}{R}}{\partial \dot V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial \frac{\dot V_C}{R}}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})-
(\frac{\partial \frac{\dot V_C*d}{R}}{\partial \dot V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial \frac{\dot V_C*d}{R}}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}})+
(\frac{\partial \frac{V_C*d}{R}}{\partial \dot V_c}*\sigma V_C\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}+\frac{\partial \frac{V_C*d}{R}}{\partial d}*\sigma d\Bigr|_{\substack{V_{CE}=5V\\D_E=0.34}}=0
\$

Comment: Mother of equations.

Comment: Run while you can

Comment: Use a little more English to help provide context. I'm sure you think, for example, that everyone should see \$V_{CE}\$ and the line you wrote above it and recognize what you meant. But that specific term has other implications in electronics and, besides, not everyone is going to just jump up and immediately understand that when you add "E" to something you mean its equilibrium. I think you owe everyone a little more English writing.

Comment: Not a problem, ill edit it now

Comment: Well I even label \$V_C = Capacitor \ Voltage\$

Comment: Doesn't look like the right track to me. Straight out of the gate you just specify L. That's usually an output. Actually, that's not even an output. It's a conclusion resulting from the process output. I have little idea about what's bounding your entering considerations. (And I still have to find out that \$V_\text{IN}=3.3\:\text{V}\$ by reading an equation. Etc.) Way too little. I don't recognize your approach. Perhaps someone else will see this differently and confirm for you. Otherwise, I suggest you write up a better spec and see if anyone offers an alternative process to follow.

Comment: Well thats not good, I already found a mistake. Will be redoing it soon anyways.

Comment: First you define onset of discontinuous mode (DCM) if desired then choose L from L=ΔI/(VΔt) by choice of Δt = on time

Comment: To stay in the continuous mode the Energy stored must exceed the load  energy per cycle. \$E = 0.5L I^2\$

Comment: Take a big step back and state what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying the find the duty cycle that delivers a certain voltage to the load. If so then say that. If not then clearly state what this question is about because a massive string of algebra is probably the wrong approach here.